# How to fix "build failed error with openCL" when using hashcat

Tags: opencl, hashcat

I am trying to crack hash+salt with hashcat. But I kept running into this issue, and could not figure out a possible way to solve it.

```
clBuildProgram(): CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE

Error returned by cvms_element_build_from_source
* Device #3: Kernel /usr/local/Cellar/hashcat/6.1.1/share/hashcat/OpenCL/m00010_a0-pure.cl build failed.
```

I am using a 15inch Macbook Pro, 2018 with specs as below:

```
* Device #1: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8850H CPU @ 2.60GHz, skipped
* Device #2: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630, 1472/1536 MB (384 MB allocatable), 24MCU
* Device #3: AMD Radeon Pro 560X Compute Engine, 4032/4096 MB (1024 MB allocatable), 16MCU
```

How could I fix this openCL problem with my mac?

Comment: Have you checked out this section of the FAQ? https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=frequently_asked_questions#what_does_the_clbuildprogram_-11_error_mean